# Modal Popups in Full Screen Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Does the viewer support anything other than a Panel for displaying alerts in full screen without using alert('text');?

We use libraries such as Bootstrap and eModal.js, but the graphics are hidden in full screen.  They only appear once you exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the modal container is not a child of the viewer container. So when you switch to full screen the viewer div gets affected the highest z-index possible (2147483647) and your dialog gets occluded. You could turn a viewer panel into a "modal" dialog or implement your own dialog from scratch but append it to viewer.container. [Here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/tree/master/5%20-%20viewer%2Bserver%2Boss%2Bderivatives/src/client/utils/ToolPanelModal) is my example of a custom viewer modal panel.

Comment: by the way... if you can flag the answer as valid, thanks!